# Order in which resolved- and processed items are populated in PublishTransaction save event

Tags: 2013-sp1, event-system, publishtransaction

I am working on the following event system:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<PublishTransaction, SaveEventArgs>(MyEventHandler, EventPhases.Initiated);

void MyEventHandler(PublishTransaction publishTransaction, SaveEventArgs saveEventArgs, EventPhases eventPhases)
{
    IdentifiableObject identifiableObject = publishTransaction.Items[0];
    if (identifiableObject.Id == "tcm:40-81620") //the test component
    {
        PublishContext publishContext = publishTransaction.PublishContexts[0];

        log.DebugFormat(
            "{0} - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = {1}; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = {2}",
            publishTransaction.State.ToString(),
            publishContext.ResolvedItems.Count,
            publishContext.ProcessedItems.Count);
    }
}
```

I need to do something with the resolved items, but I wasn't getting the behaviour I was expecting, so I decided to log the PublishTransactionState, ResolvedItems and ProcessedItems. In the handler I have set the code to run just for a single test component in order not to get logs for other transactions. The test component is being rendered with two templates.

Here is the log I get(using log4net):

```
WaitingForPublish - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 0; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 0
InProgress -  publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 0; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 0
Resolving - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 0; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 0
Rendering - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 0; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 0
Rendering - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 0; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 2
ReadyForTransport - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 2; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 2
ReadyForTransport - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 2; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 2
WaitingForDeployment - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 2; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 2
Success - publishContext[0].ResolvedItems.Count = 2; publishContext[0].ProcessedItems.Count = 2
```

Can someone please explain the following:

- Why is the 'PublishContext[0].ProcessedItems' populated prior to 'PublishContext[0].ResolvedItems?
- Why are there two 'Rendering' states?
  In question [PublishTransaction save event triggered multiple times](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/publishtransaction-save-event-triggered-multiple-times) Rick Pannekoek states that "In general, the Save event is called for any save (change) of the PublishTransaction, not only for state changes" which is clear, however I can't seem to find out which property change is causing this. Is there an easy way to find out what is causing this save?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Why are there two 'Rendering' states?` isn't this because you're rendering two component presentations?

Comment: Can you share your event handler code please so that we can see how/where you're calling the log statements?

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders
Hm, possibly. I was expecting a single Rendering since they're all part of the same transaction. I will add a third CT and verify. I will post a comment once I've tried it.

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov,

Sure, I've updated the original description.

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders, adding a third CT resulted in a second ReadyForTransport appearing, while two Rendering-s remained. So that confirms that it's unrelated to the number of templates involved. The event gets triggered by some property change. At this point I've pretty much given up on finding out which one, it was just a side-question :). However the main dilemma remains, why does the processed items get populated before the resolved items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the "Why are there two 'Rendering' states?", or more accurately "Why are there two Save events with State 'Rendering'?": you already more or less answered the question yourself -- the first one is for the State change to 'Rendering', the second one for changing the `ProcessedItems`.

IIRC, the `ResolvedItems` property is derived from `ProcessedItems`. I think this derivation happens when loading the item. That would explain why you don't see them yet in the Save event that happens when `ProcessedItems` are set. It also matters to which Event Phase ypu subscribed.